# Use for /f information (IP with variations given a sub net mask) to launch remote connection program?

Tags: batch-file

What I'd like to do :

. Find and calculate (via user input) the IP of a remote machine by searching a .txt file and pipe that information to the connection program;

My batch so far :

```
@Echo off
mode con: cols=50 lines=20
Title direct connect
:start
color 0A
cls
Set Var=
SET /P var= Name:
FINDSTR %var% C:\IP_LAN.txt
Pause
```

. At this point I get the result : 10001;225.225.225.192;192.192.192.1 (name;subnet mask;IP)

Then if I use FOR /F :

```
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=; " %%a in ('FINDSTR %var% C:\IP_LAN.txt') DO @echo 2nd token "%%a" 3rd token "%%b"
```

I get indeed :

```
Name:10001
10001;225.225.225.192;192.192.192.1
2nd token "225.225.225.192" 3rd token "192.192.192.1"
```

I would like to use the 2nd and 3rd token in the following matter:

Where IF 2nd=225.225.225.192 THEN 3rd would be +38 (192.192.192.1==>192.192.192.39)

Where IF 2nd=225.225.225.224 THEN 3rd would be +17 (192.192.192.1==>192.192.192.18)

To be use as **host** in:

```
start "C:\Program Files\UltraVNC" vncviewer.exe -connect -4greycolors **host** ::xxxx -Password xxxxxx
```

This is my first real batch and I've tried my best for the last 2 days but I'm apparently stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If any answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: @JosefZ I've accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next code snippet should work. Pay your attention to the `:getX` computational subroutine:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
:: 
:: don't let %var% empty as 'FINDSTR C:\IP_LAN.txt' will wait for user input
Set "Var=xxx"
SET /P "var= Name: "

for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=;" %%a in ('FINDSTR %var% C:\IP_LAN.txt') DO (
    @echo 2nd token "%%a" 3rd token "%%b"
    if "%%a"=="225.225.225.192" call :Getx "%%b" 38
    if "%%a"=="225.225.225.224" call :Getx "%%b" 17
  )
:: further code


goto :eof
:getX
set "hostIP="
set "iiPlus="   
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%A in ("%~1") DO (
    set "hostIP=%%A.%%B.%%C"
    set /A "iiPlus=%%D + %~2"   
  )
echo start ... host %hostIP%.%iiPlus%
goto :eof
```

However, your `start` command may not work as expected because the first parameter surrounded by double quotes will treat as command title; try next syntax template:

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

**Edit: output** (with another file name instead of `C:\IP_LAN.txt`, see `type`). The *:: further code* comment is pointing that more code is *facultative*, *optional*.

```
==>type D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\30443425.txt
10001;225.225.225.192;192.192.192.1
10002;225.225.225.224;192.192.192.1

==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30443425a.bat
Name: 10001
2nd token "225.225.225.192" 3rd token "192.192.192.1"
start ... host 192.192.192.39

==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30443425a.bat
Name: 10002
2nd token "225.225.225.224" 3rd token "192.192.192.1"
start ... host 192.192.192.18
```

Next output could happen as well:

```
==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30443425a.bat
Name: 225
2nd token "225.225.225.192" 3rd token "192.192.192.1"
start ... host 192.192.192.39
2nd token "225.225.225.224" 3rd token "192.192.192.1"
start ... host 192.192.192.18
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~A`, `%~1` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: @ JosefZ Thank you so much! I'll try this today. Also thank you for the comment on the start command since I was actually getting a .exe not found error.

Comment: @ JosefZ As such it does not work. If I understand correctly "%~1" stands for %%b (the IP address) and %~2 for either 17 or 38. No error displayed, the window fades away. Is the comment ':: further code' pointing that more code is needed? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I finally got it, I just had to change the syntax here : `start "VNC" /D "C:\Program Files\UltraVNC" vncviewer.exe -connect -4greycolors host %hostIP%.%iiPlus%::5631 -Password xxxxx`. Yesterday I was at work and out of focus apparently. It worked perfectly, thank you so very much for your help, concise and to the point I feel like my knowledge leaped to another stage entirely.